# Canada Tourist Visa Application

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas

I was filling out the application form for Canada visitor visa application. 
Some background, I am an Indian citizien working full time in the united states and currently on F1 visa.

I have the following questions regarding the application:

1. Personal Details, Section 7- Country of Residence

   Here I have to enter the start and end date of my visa.
   Will the date be the issue and expiry date of my F1 visa ?
2. Details of my visit to Canada, Section 4

   It asks for the address and name of the person I am visiting there
   I dont have any immediate family members living in canada. I am not sure what 
   to enter in this feild
3. Details of my visit to Canada, Section 3

   There may not be a specific answer for this but how much money am I expected 
   to have to show that I am capable of funding my own expenses in canada ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. The dates refer to the start and end of the immigration status you've specified for your country of residence. In your case, that would mean your F1 visa.
2. The idea behind this section is to get a sense of who you will be visiting and what you will be doing in Canada. If you don't plan to meet anyone and are going purely for touristic purposes, you could include the name and address of your hotel. Otherwise, name any people and/or institutions that you plan to visit.
3. You guessed correctly - there is no magic number. Think about what would be reasonable, based on the duration and nature of your stay. Living in a hotel is obviously more expensive than living in a youth hostel, which is in turn more expensive than living with a friend. Food can sometimes be more expensive in major Canadian cities than in the States, as can be travel within Canada. If you haven't booked return flights, include the costs of that too. Calculate a figure for your trip that makes sense in the context of your plans, and add some margin to it, just in case. 
   If your trip is long, and/or complicated, it may make sense to attach an additional page to your letter of explanation, and break down how (and how much)  you plan to pay for everything.

Official guidance for filling the form is available [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5256-applying-visitor-visa-temporary-resident-visa.html#5256E4).

Comment: My planned trip is very short. About 3-4 days. I do have a friend there who is a student. So maybe I can list that as my means of stay ? 
Also is there a minimum advisable amount ?

Comment: There isn't a minimum advisable amount, but for a 3-4 day trip, you probably don't need a lot. A credit card, and a bank balance of around $500 - $1000 should be more than adequate in my opinion, although as I said, the final judgment will be made by the visa officer.

Comment: Ohh, So should I include the credit card statements too along with the bank statements ?

Comment: @john There's no harm doing it.